# Capybara / PhantomJS client died while processing

Tags: cucumber, capybara, phantomjs

Im randomly getting this error on CI

```
PhantomJS client died while processing {"name":"evaluate","args":["jQuery.active"]} (Capybara::Poltergeist::DeadClient)
```

Error is happening in this function :

```
def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_wait_time) do
      element = false
      until element do
        begin
          element = page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active') == 0
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Anyone have an idea why is this randomly failing?

Comment: I know this is close to deadposting, but I'm having the same issue inside a Timeout, while running spec/capybara on Jenkins. Did you ever manage to fix these random failures?